# Where is the value stored for a one2many table initially in OpenERP6.1

Tags: python, odoo

I would like to know as to where is the value stored for a one2many table initially in OpenERP6.1?
i.e if we create a record for a one2many table,this record will be actually
saved to the database table only after saving the record of the main table
associated with this, even though we can create many records(rows) for one2many
table.

Where are these rows stored?

Are they stored in any OpenERP memory variable? if so which is that variable
or function with which we can access those..

Please help me out on this.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

When saving a new record in openerp, a dictionary will be generated with all the fields having data as keys and its data as values. If the field is a one2many and have many lines, then a list of dictionaries will be the value for the one2many field. You can modify it by overriding the `create` and `write` functions in openerp.

Comment: Yes AnomA..but the create and write functions of one2many fields will be invoked only while inserting the data to parent table as per the current architecture.My requirement is to check for duplicate records in one2many table before the record is inserted into parent table.possibly on an onchange function..

Comment: it the child records are already there in the database, then why cant you use many2many? in the xml, use widget='many2many'

Answer (score 0):

One2Many field is child parent relation in OpenERP. One2Many is just logical field there is no effect in database for that.

If you are creating Sale order then Sale order line is One2Many in Sale order model. But if you will not put Many2One in Sale order line then One2Many in Sale order will not work.

Many2One field put foreign key for the related model in the current table.

Answer (score 0):

When you define o2m field you have to create one m2o field in relation table which we will refer in o2m as second Param. Now Database point of view o2m field does not exists at all. Rather we store information on relation table e.g.

```
OpenERP Code:
modelA                 MOdel B
o2m_field   -------->  m2o_field 

While Databvase picture is 

tableA                    TableB
                        m2o_field (FK)
```

Now, we need to show the o2m field values in Client framework search for in relation table m2o field with id= current record and here you are with result.

Thank You

Comment: I know that once the modelA is saved, the rows in o2m field is stored in tableB.But before saving the modelA, the framework is temporarily storing all the rows in o2m field somewhere.Where is that? Because I need to validate the o2m rows before the modelA is Saved.